# Domain for a complex function

Tags: complex-analysis

For which $z$ values is the complex function below undefined?

$$\frac{1}{e^z-1}$$

Am I under thinking this problem, or shouldn't the domain be all complex values except for $z=0$?

Comment: Are you saying that $e^z$ never equals one unless $z=0$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's undefined when $e^z=1,$ and notice that $e^{\pm2\pi i} = 1$ and $e^{\pm4\pi i} = 1,$ etc.

The slightly more involved question is how do we know there are no other points where it's undefined? And there you need to observe that $e^z$ is defined for all values of $z.$ And also ask yourself how you know that there are no *other* values of $z$ for which $z=1$ than the ones included in the "etc." of the first paragraph above.

Comment: I can easily state all the values of $z$ for which $z = 1$... I think.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: The complex exponential is periodic. Consider the trigonometric definition of $\exp(z)$ or more clearly $\exp(ix)$.